# Share is not supported when you are in Spaces. Gradio&Hugging face's Spaces

Tags: huggingface, gradio

Basiclly problem is that i can only run my space locally. Either error is "To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.", and after doing that RuntimeError: "Share is not supported when you are in Spaces."

```
intf = gr.Interface(fn=classify_image, inputs=image, outputs=label, examples=examples)
intf.launch(inline=True, share=True)
```

Anyway to fix it? And what could cause it? It runs locally perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

You just need to disable sharing feature
`intf.launch(inline=True)`